# Keepass auto-type is not working with on QEMU

Tags: qemu, keepass

I'm trying to use the auto-type feature of Keepass to enter my github password from inside a QEMU virtual machine.

The problem is that it fails to type digits, instead it types the character below the digits (I have an french azerty keyboard so for example `"` instead of `3`).

The guest OS is Fedora 27. I tried messing with localectl without success. Also launching the VM with and without `-k fr` and setting caps lock have no effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of solved my problem by not using the QEMU window and connecting via SSH in a standard terminal.